# Umbraco v4 console Api

Tags: umbraco, umbraco4

I was wondering if there is any console api similar to 
https://github.com/sitereactor/umbraco-console-example

but for Version 4 of Umbraco.

Comment: There was a discussion regarding this API on [OUR Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/39164-Console-Application-Publishing-Problem). They have discussed issues (problem with v6 is one of them) with this solution, alongside the potential alternatives. Morten has a [good explanation of the process](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/39164-Console-Application-Publishing-Problem#comment-142938) and Kevin has made a [custom solution](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/39164-Console-Application-Publishing-Problem#comment-189720).

Comment: If this post doesn't help you, I would consider posting a question on OUR Umbraco and linking this question post also.

Comment: Not to my knowledge :-/ The old v4 core was depending on HttpContext among other things, which makes a standalone app very difficult.to do.

Comment: @MarkoJ. Thanks for your comment. As far as I can see they are discussing issues around publishing content into Umbraco and especially issues with cache in umbraco. What if I want to pull data from Umbraco to be inserted to another custom database? Is there going to be issues with console api as well?  I did post this question on [OUR Umbraco](https://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions//73144-umbraco-v4-console-api) as well

Comment: @JannikAnker Yes I guessed that as well, I suppose if I have a web application connected to Umbraco, in there I'll have the Context to work with. But I like to know if it is possible to do CRUD operations with a console app or not. If not is it possible to fetch the data out and use it in another data store.